# How to parse this XML using linq to xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

i am trying to parse following xml but no sucess any one guide me what mistake am i doing here

```
 string feedURL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/arabic/index.xml";
 XDocument feedSource;
        feedSource = XDocument.Load(feedURL);

 var another = (from myFeed in feedSource.Descendants("entry")
                         select new
                         {
                             feedTitle = myFeed.Element("title").Value,
                             //feedDescription = myFeed.Element("description").Value,
                             //feedLink = myFeed.Element("link").Value,
                             feedpubDate = myFeed.Element("published") != null ? myFeed.Element("published").Value : null
                             //feedcategory = myFeed.Element("category") != null ? myFeed.Element("category").Value : null,
                             //feedItems = myFeed.Descendants("entry")
                         }
        );


            if (another != null && another.Count() > 0)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("No Record Found");
            }
```

it is showing me no record found.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too certain about this (and unable to test on this pc), but try `from myFeed in feedSource.Element("feed").Elements("entry")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in LINQPad:

```
XNamespace xns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.bbc.co.uk/arabic/index.xml");
xdoc.Element(xns + "feed").Elements(xns + "entry");
```

Problem was the lacking namespace.

Comment: yes but it is giving me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in select new { } body...